# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck in boot

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia

After installing `nvidia computing tools` , And `cuda` And also `VLC` player I restarted machine .
And it stucks in `ubuntu` Logo .

With `ctrl alt F2` it will go to black screen with a message

> A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up

And i cant write any command  here .

I thinks the problem is in `grub` configs , but i cant write any command .

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bootable drive (the one you installed Ubuntu with), you can boot up into the Live environment to recover.  Another option on some systems is while your machine is booting at the logo hitting  or  can bring up the boot messages as well.

To get to the grub menu so you can make configuration changes, start your system and wait for the GRUB menu (if you don't see a GRUB menu, press and hold the left Shift key right after starting the system).

You can also select a kernel and press the e key then go to the line that starts with "linux" and remove "quiet" and "splash" and continue the boot to see the boot messages.

Comment: I have bootable usb , i tried live ubuntu but grub config is read only mode

Comment: Are you able to see any boot messages by disabling quite mode or splash?  You could also boot up into the ubuntu live cd and mount the disk to make disk file modifications.

Comment: I cant disable quite mode .  How can i do that ?

Comment: See the answer - You get to the grub menu and select the kernel, hit "e" and remove "quite" and "splash" from the line, then continue the boot with ctrl-x (or whatever it prompts you to do to continue)

Comment: Yeah now logs are coming . Top logs are OK . But at the end  is " A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up  "

Comment: Maybe you can post a snapshot of your logs in your original question and someone could help you further debug.